# Selenium: findElements by class xpath, before a specific element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a page with a layout like this:

```
<div class="cool nice">...</div>  //1
<div class="cool nice">...</div>  //2
<div class="cool nice">...</div>  //3
<div class="cool nice">...</div>  //4
<div class="separator element">...</div>
<div class="cool nice">...</div>  //5
<div class="cool nice">...</div>  //6
```

I can get all elements with `class="cool nice"` like this:

```
List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='cool nice']"));
```

However, I'd like to exclude elements that follow the element with `class="separator element`. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a not in there it seems to me:

```
//*[@class="cool nice" and not(./preceding::*[@class="separator element"])]
```

Comment: Which elements would it return? 1-4 or 5-6?

Comment: 1-4 only. Because 5-6 match the not condition. Right?

Comment: Yes. I tested it and it seems to be working fine when the separator element is present. However when it's not, it seems to stop adding valid elements at some random point.

Comment: Okay I tested it some more and it works fine, it seems. It must have been my mess up! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use `preceding-sibling` or `preceding`

```
//div[@class='separator element']/preceding::div[@class='cool nice']
```

OR

```
//div[@class='separator element']/preceding-sibling::div[@class='cool nice']
```

Try now

```
List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath(" //div[@class='separator element']/preceding-sibling::div[@class='cool nice']"));
```

Comment: Sometimes there is no `separator element` on a page, then all elements should be added. Would it work for such a case? Also - I use a path like this: `//*`. Should I modify your code like this: `List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath(" //*div[@class='separator element']/preceding-sibling::div[@class='cool nice']"));`?

Comment: No this doesn't quite work and also it will return elements in reverse.